# Web API 2 Owin Refresh Token doesn't work and return invalid_grant before its expiry time

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2, owin

Refresh token works fine for 2 to 3 days but after few days it stops working.

**On Authentication** call for

> grant_type = refresh_token

IIS return Bad request 400 with error message

> {error : "invalid_grant"}

**temporary solution**

it works fine by restarting/recycling API instance on IIS.

Unable to find what is the issue with the IIS or the Owin why it works fine for few days while i have set an expiry time of 30 days for the refresh token.

This is the code used for refresh token

```
    var token = new RefreshToken()
    {
        RefreshTokenId = refreshTokenId,
        ClientId = clientid,
        UserEmail = context.Ticket.Identity.Name != clientid ? context.Ticket.Identity.Name : null,
        IssuedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
        ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30)
    };

    context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedOn;
    context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = token.ExpiresOn;

    token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();
```

I will be thankful for Any help regarding this issue.

Comment: I've added a provisional answer on the assumption that your refresh token is intended to be longer lived than your access token, but it's expiring when your refresh token does. If that's not the case, please let me know and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: its already set to 30 days hence this is not the case

Comment: What is the expiration time of the access token? Can you add the provider code where the refresh token request is handled?

Comment: Access token time is one day

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem...

Comment: No I haven't found the solution yet

Comment: Same problem.... Did you find a solution ?

Comment: No I haven't found the solution

Comment: I have the same problem, but mine work just for some hours although I set the expiration to some month...

Comment: any luck with a solution yet? same here

Comment: No solution found yet

Comment: @GhulamMohayudin Did you find any solution for this? We are facing the same issue.

Comment: @AshutoshChamoli Not yet

Comment: @GhulamMohayudin Any suggestions on what we can try, for us, the API generates token at inconsistent times. And what you have tried out till now?

Answer (score 0):

IIS by default recycles your app pool by calling a garbage collector to clear the memory on every 20 minutes, So if you store the refresh tokens in the ram (ex: a static dictionary or whatever data structure) they will be cleaned after the recycling. That's why the refresh tokens will no longer be valid even if their life time is longer.

Comment: i have described in my question it works 2 to 3 days some time, not 20 minutes